# python script is not showing in jobs

Tags: server, scripts, ssh, python

I have a `python` script to run a flask application in `ubuntu server`.
I ssh'ed to the system and ran the flask server with `python run.py` in `debug mode` , to see the debug info.

```
app.run(host='0.0.0.0',port=5000,debug=True)
```

Somehow I got disconnected to the session as I came to my home network , and when I ssh'ed again I could see that the script is still running( not sure if saying running in background would be correct ).

```
ubuntu@ip-11-11-11-11:~$ ps -aux | grep python
root       800  0.0  1.4 170820 15096 ?        Ssl  May02   0:00 /usr/bin/python3 /usr/bin/networkd-dispatcher --run-startup-triggers
root       858  0.0  1.5 187636 16100 ?        Ssl  May02   0:00 /usr/bin/python3 /usr/share/unattended-upgrades/unattended-upgrade-shutdown --wait-for-signal
ubuntu   13069  0.0  2.1  58744 21408 pts/1    S+   10:20   0:00 python webhook.py
ubuntu   13071  0.2  2.2 213440 22876 pts/1    Sl+  10:20   0:22 /usr/bin/python /home/ubuntu/webhook.py
ubuntu   13380  0.0  0.1  13136  1008 pts/0    S+   13:13   0:00 grep --color=auto python
```

and the port number associated with the flask server is open as well.

```
ubuntu@ip-11-11-11-11:~$ netstat -tunapl | grep LISTEN
(Not all processes could be identified, non-owned process info
 will not be shown, you would have to be root to see it all.)
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.53:53           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5000            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      13069/python
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      -
```

I wanted to see the debug info again , so I thought to use `fg` to bring it into foreground. but there is no output for `jobs`.

```
ubuntu@ip-11-11-11-11:~$ jobs
ubuntu@ip-11-11-11-11:~$
```

I believe it means that python script is a process not job.

Can someone please help me with this , Is there any way I can bring the python script back in the command line.
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, you're asking if there's a way to recover a bash session you disconnected from (because you've ssh'd in again, you're now in a different session).

[This post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/598/can-i-connect-to-or-view-abandoned-ssh-sessions) has the general version of your question. The verdict seems to be that you can't recover control of the full bash session.

However, if you just need to see debugging output, it might be enough to just view stdout from the Flask process. [This post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/58550/how-to-view-the-output-of-a-running-process-in-another-bash-session) has some discussion of viewing stdout on a running process (disclaimer: haven't tried it myself)